# How do plasma arc speakers work? Also, Bass?

Tags: speakers, sound, arc

Please see the following videos for examples of what I am asking about : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeIAkKmUfn4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rasp88nbsRw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lES6kWfHrsU

Is there a reasonably simple explanation for how they work?

Also, is it possible to create bass frequencies with a plasma arc speaker?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_speaker)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can be answered with a quick trip to google or wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Plasma is **HOT** the more current you force through an air plasma, the more it is heated and expands. The air plasma pushes other air around it out of the way, the same as the driver/cone in a 'conventional' speaker.
2. Plasma speaker arcs are generally not very physically large. Reproducing bass frequencies with high volume requires moving a relativel 'high volume' of air; thus most plasma arc speakers have limited bass response.